# Difference between Dashboard and Menu

Tags: mobile-application, dashboard

I am a senior high school student and our research is to create a something that will use java. So we came up with a mobile application, my question is what is the difference between navigation menu and dashboard? Is dashboard also called home page? Hope you can help me. Thankyou!!

Comment: You might want to take this opportunity to let your teacher know that Java is a dying technology. To prepare you for the future, you should be researching serverless.

Comment: @plainclothes they're probably learning programming. Serverless is an OOP web architecture. It has to be a programming language. The first thing you learn in Java class is there has to be a better way.

Comment: @moot The first thing you learn with serverless is that it *is* the better way 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer: a dashboard is an extension of a menu.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_(computing)):

> In computing and telecommunications, a **menu** is a list of options or commands presented to the user of a computer or communications system. A menu may either be a system's entire user interface, or only part of a more complex one.

A **dashboard** is a software manifestation of a physical dashboard: a single area to access and control multiple functions of a product, such as your car dashboard. However, by achieving similar functionality, a dashboard could be considered an extended menu. The extension usually comes from data visualization and manipulation: statuses, tables, charts, variety of controls, etc.

A homepage could contain both menus and a dashboard. In the following example, the left-hand column is a menu, while the center view is a dashboard:

[image]